# PostGIS 2.1 error install with shared object (rtpostgis-2.1.so") Linux Mint

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, linux

I've Installed Linux Mint 16 mate and install PostGIS with PostGreSQL (I've tried many ways in the Internet from original source to some suggestion) but all is too error: "
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": libxerces-c-3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Please help me for fix this problem because I can't understand how to fix this. Please, note that in "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib" has file rtpostgis-2.1.so.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to add the output of the command `sudo ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so` please. Also, how exactly did you install PostGIS - from where, using which packages, which commands, etc? (Comment when you've made the edit, it'll notify me).

Comment: Thanks pro Underdark but I think the problem is that with Linux Mint OS because I can easily install PostGIS in same Linux Ubuntu OS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yours is not the first report I've seen of brokenness in Linux Mint, so I would not be surprised. My previous request stands: You're missing some important details in your question.

Comment: Looks like you are getting hung up on a GDAL dependency.  rtpostgis-2.1.so depends on GDAL which in turn can depend on a ton of other packages depending on how its compiled.  Sounds like your GDAL is missing the libxerces dependency its looking for.  As Craig says do do an ldd to better see where the error is.